# A file is not moving from temp to upload folder

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $filename =strtolower(basename($_FILES['resume']['name']));
    $ext = $_FILES["resume"]["type"];
    $size= $_FILES["resume"]["size"];

    if (!empty($filename) && (($ext == "application/msword") ||
       ($ext  == "application/pdf") && ($size < 500000))) {
        $name = $_POST['name']; 
        $email_address = $_POST['email'];
        $nwname=str_replace(" ","",$name);
        $newfilename= substr(md5(rand() * time()),0,7);
        $newfilename2 =$nwname."_".$newfilename;
        if($ext == 'application/msword') {
            $newname ='upload/'.$newfilename2.".doc";
        } else if($ext == 'application/pdf'){
            $newname ='upload/'.$newfilename2.".pdf";
        }
        $temp= $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
        echo $temp;

        $move = @move_uploaded_file($temp,$newname)
                    or die('Updoaling error.');
        echo $move; 

        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE saxet SET filelocation='$newname'
            WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email_address'");
    }
}
```

My file with name "`$filename`" is not moving to the temporary folder. Can help me in this?

Comment: Start by showing error messages and remove the `@` from the call to move_uploaded_file

Comment: Remove the @ in @move_uploaded_file($temp,$newname) to see the errors if any.

Comment: there can be so many possibilities.. but to check, you can echo $temp and $newname. if they are coming properly then your code should work.   also remove @ from the begining of move_uploaded_file

Comment: yup by mistake tht @ was added..........i have removed it....and yes i have echoed both temp as well as newname and both are working but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the permission to write file on upload folder.

Comment: i have checked and upload folder is writable.

Comment: for other too,check it must be 777

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [is_writable()](http://php.net/is_writable) function to determine if the destination is writable before moving the uploaded file there.

Also, `@` is an [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).  It suppresses errors from `move_uploaded_file()`.  Anytime you're using `@` and getting unexpected functionality it's a good idea to remove the `@` and see if any errors show up.

Comment: yes I have use @ for this purpose only but it doesn't shows nythng

Answer (score 0):

Give proper permissions to the folder where uploaded files are stored.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/folder
```

also check and change ownership

```
shudo chown root:www /var/www/html/folder
```

Change the path to yours.